# Is Beau’s mom really a wealthy and powerful woman?

Tags: plot-explanation, beau-is-afraid

In the movie *Beau Is Afraid*, Beau's mom is portrayed as a powerful, over-bearing, and wealthy woman.

Since the entire movie is heavily subject to viewers' interpretation, i.e., not everything we see on the screen is real, I am wondering if his mom is really a powerful and wealthy woman in reality.

Why would an over-bearing, wealthy and influential mom leave her son to live in an apartment that is in a bad neighbourhood and in really bad shape?

Answer (score 1):

> Why would an over-bearing, wealthy and influential mom leave her son to live in an apartment that is in a bad neighbourhood and in really bad shape?

**Surface-level answer**: She's a vindictive, evil character.

**Deeper answer**: She probably owns the very building he lives in and uses her vast resources to manipulate Beau as if he were in The Truman Show. She may have manipulated him into such a rough area as a way to draw him back to her.

Beau notices his building on some kind of printed advertisement when walking around his mother's house:

[image]